# sequelize's raw query not commiting to file

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

The following code seems to work just fine, processing and does print to console the raw query as intended. However, the database file doesn't show anything that was supposed to be written there.

```js
sequelize.query(`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'buscars' (termo,valor) VALUES ('${termo}', '${args.join(' ')}')`);
```

The whole code is:

```js
require('http').createServer().listen(3000);
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const c = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const prefix = '!';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  //logging: false,
  // SQLite only
  storage: 'db.sqlite',
});

const Tags = sequelize.define('buscars', {
  termo: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    unique: true,
  },
  valor: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    defaultValue: '',
  }
});

const Tags2 = sequelize.define('pessoas', {
  nome: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    unique: true,
  },
  tempo: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    defaultValue: '',
  }
});


client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
  //Tags.sync({ force: false });
  //Tags2.sync({ force: false });

});

client.login(c.token);

client.on('message', message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const termo = args.shift();
  var cargo = message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "sensei");
  if (command === 'novo') {
    if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "sensei")) {
      sequelize.query(`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'buscars' (termo,valor) VALUES ('${termo}', '${args.join(' ')}')`);
      message.channel.send(`nova entrada: ${termo}\\nvalor: ${args.join(' ')}`);
      message.channel.send(`${cargo}`);
    } else { message.channel.send(`Área restrita, acesso apenas para Senseis :3`); }
  }
});
```

Comment: 1. You need to await `sequelize.query`
2. Are you sure you insert a non-duplicating record?

Comment: Anatoly, changed the command to:-> add = async function(x,y) {await sequelize.query(`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'buscars' (termo,valor) VALUES ('${x}', '${y}')`)}; <- and invoked as -> add(termo,args.join(' ')); <- but nothing changed, it outputs the command to console but doesn't write on the db file

Comment: What about my second question? Dif you try to remove `OR IGNORE` ?

Comment: the "or ignore" piece is for when there are duplicates, however as of now there's not even entries on the database yet